# How to center the comment icon at different screen size?

Tags: css, media-queries, center, text-align

Is there a way that I can center the comment icon at a different screen size?

I tried text align center and put display to block, but it makes the alignment go wrong, so I chose span instead
http://jsfiddle.net/fkp8d/889/

```
<div class="socialBar">
      <a href="https://" target='_blank'> 
        <i class="like-icon"></i> <span class="sq-text">Like</span> 
         // center the comment icon at different screen size. 
         // tried text align center and put display to block , 
         // but it make the alignment not correct,so I chose span instead
        <i class="comment-icon"></i> <span class="sq-text">Comment</span> 
        <span style="float:right;margin-right:10px;">
           <i class="share-icon"></i> <span class="sq-text">Share</span>  
        </span> 
      </a>
 </div>

.like-icon {         
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(//);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 3px;
  background-size: 13px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 13px; 
  margin-left: 11px;
}


.comment-icon {
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: url(//);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 13px;
 height: 13px;
 width: 13px;  
}
.share-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(//);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px  
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: use media queries... example @media screen and ( max-width: 600px) {  change your css here }

Comment: I used media queries , but it does not center it even thought I use .comment-icon{ left-margin: n%};

Comment: any reason to have all icons inside the same `a` tag?

Comment: just want to link all icons to the same webpage

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/fkp8d/891/  ??

Comment: @DaniP Yes something like that! Thank you!

Comment: will post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can
1. Center align the text within the .socialBar with `text-align:center`
2. wrap the Share text & icon with a span that floats right with `float:right`, 
3. wrap the like & like icon with `float:left`.

An issue with floating elements is that, the height will not be auto-calculated. You have to clear the floats manually. So I have added `Clearfix`

```css
.like-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(//);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 3px;
  background-size: 13px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 13px;
  margin-left: 11px;
}
.comment-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(//);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
}
.share-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(//);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.socialBar {
  text-align: center;
}
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* start commented backslash hack \*/

* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
  display: block;
}
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

```html
<div class="socialBar clearfix">
  <a href="https://" target='_blank'>
    <span class="float-left">
        <i class="like-icon"></i> <span class="sq-text">Like</span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a href="https://" target='_blank'>
    <i class="comment-icon"></i>  <span class="sq-text">Comment</span> 
  </a>
  <a href="https://" target='_blank'>
    <span class="float-right">
           <i class="share-icon"></i> <span class="sq-text">Share</span> 
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice to include the clearfix, but all that can be resumed to just `clearfix:after{content:""; display:table; clear:both;}`

Comment: Old habit to copy & paste extra styles written for cross browser compatibility. Yep, you are correct if you consider IE9 above then the one you suggested will work

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I've changed the html structure, You really want seperated anchor tags `<a></a>` for each action (like share.. etc)

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fkp8d/892/

```
<div class="socialBar">
  <div class="socialCenter">
      <a href="https://" target='_blank'> 
        <i class="like-icon"></i>
        <span class="sq-text">Like</span>  
      </a>
      <a href="https://" target='_blank'> 
        <i class="comment-icon"></i>
        <span class="sq-text">Comment</span> 
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="socialRight">
      <a href="https://" target="_blank">
         <i class="share-icon"></i>
         <span class="sq-text">Share</span>
      </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.like-icon {         
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(//);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 3px;
  background-size: 13px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 13px; 
  margin-left: 11px;
}


.comment-icon {
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: url(//);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 13px;
 height: 13px;
 width: 13px;  
}
.share-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(//);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px  
}

.socialBar {
  text-align: center;
}

.socialCenter,
.socialRight {
  display: inline-block;
}
.socialRight {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is making an `a` tag for each element and then use this trick based on `text-align:justify` to get the desired output:

```css
.socialBar {
  text-align: justify;
}
.socialBar:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.socialBar i {
  background:black;
  display:inline-block;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialBar">
  <a href="#"><i class="like-icon"></i>Like</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="comment-icon"></i>Comment</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="share-icon"></i>Share</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="socialBar">
    <a href="#" class="like"> 
        <i class="like-icon"></i> <span class="sq-text">Like</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="comment"> 
        <i class="comment-icon"></i> <span class="sq-text">Comment</span> 
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="share">
        <i class="share-icon"></i> <span class="sq-text">Share</span>  
    </a>
 </div>
<style>
.socialBar{
text-align:center;
width:100%;
}
.socialBar a{
text-align:center;
}
.like{
float:left;
}
.share{
float:right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your media query, give this a shot for class sq-text.

```
width: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50px;
text-align: center;
```

Of course, you should be containing the icon within a parent element.